# How to authenticate django static file access?

Tags: django, authentication

I am developing a site that uses DJANGO basic auth: django.contrib.auth
It works fine, and only logged in user can visit a page. However, I find that the auth cannot apply to static file.

e.g. one page loads a static file video, the user needs to log in to view but I can use f12 to find the path.
`http://example.org/static/media/test.mp4`

and after I log out the user, I can still use the above url to directly access the static file without auth. I tried several methods but they are not working. Is that possible to add auth to static file path?

Answer (score 2):

Serving media files with django

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings


@login_required
def protected_serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    return serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], protected_serve, 
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```